# Is it possible to make a Windows 10 taskbar icon unclickable/non-highlightable?

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, icons

I currently am using a couple of do-nothing batch programs, with background coloured icons, as taskbar separators (the only way I could find to partition icons on my taskbar).

I would like to make these two icons unclickable. Preferably, I would also like the icon to not even highlight as the cursor passes over them.

Does anyone have any ideas about how this could be achieved, or if it is even possible.

Thanks

Comment: I don't believe this is possible, but if it is, Stardock's [WindowBlinds](https://www.stardock.com/products/windowblinds/) would likely be the best option.  _(With that being said, I created a 1500+ piece custom theme in Windows 8 and I never came across such an edit in WindowBlinds or the registry.)_ 
 What you may want to look into is [RainMeter](https://www.rainmeter.net/), however this is more a workaround, allowing  creation of a custom taskbar, but it would either be an addition to _(i.e. use Rainmeter's taskbar and make Windows' show on mouseover)_ or repalcement of the Windows taskbar

Comment: Hmmm I suspected as much, disappointing but not unexpected. Thankyou for your answer and for the links to WindowBlinds and RainMeter. I will check them out.